# Exception has occurred. _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, null

How is Null Safety in this code

```
class EditProduct extends StatelessWidget {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

The line of code with the problem: `_formKey.currentState!.validate()`

```
ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      updateProduct().then((value) {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => HomePage()));
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text("save"))
```

Answer (score 0):

to use form key you need to add the Form widget and into that widget, you need to pass formKey in the property key like this :

```
Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child // your textfields.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you assigned `_formkey` inside the form widget?

```
    Form(
       key: _formKey,
       child : ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
        updateProduct().then((value) {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HomePage()));
            },
         );
      }
    },
    child: Text("save"),
  ),
),
```

Comment: if you want to add _formkey first you have to wrap your widget widget with Form widget then assign the globle key and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
        updateProduct().then((value) {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HomePage()));
            },
         );
      }
    },
    child: Text("save"),
  ),
),
```